# Could I print "current line and statement" to stdout in pytest?

Tags: python, logging, output, pytest

Could I print "current line and statement" to `stdout`  in `pytest`?
I want to modify `pytest` files to achieve the following:

```
line 9: snmp_get(node1.1)
line 10: snmp_set(nod1.2)
```

Anyone can tell me where to modify?

Thanks!

Comment: the issue is resolved in pytest group: Ronny :  so am i asuming it correct that you want *python* to print line numbers
and statements as it executes your code, since py.test tests executing
are just python code running

you can do that by implementing a own trace function (sys.settrace) and
hooking into pytest_runtest_call for example

Comment: That's ok, Thank you!